# Getting json data from url

Tags: discord.js

How do I get a JSON response from  URL?
In my case, the URL is `https://api.mathjs.org/v4/?expr=2*2` JSON response and then whenever someone types !test it sends the json/data from the URL.

Comment: the api dont return a json response? just a text one, maybe you could use node-fetch and use <response>.text()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is some sample code using [node-fetch](https://www.npmjs.com/node-fetch), I cant guarantee it will work well

```js
const fetch = require('node-fetch')

(async () => {
const response = await fetch(`https://api.mathjs.org/v4/?expr=${encodeURIComponent(2*2)}`).then(r => r.text())
console.log(response)
})()
```

this logs `4`.

this is a sample code as i said,
you would have to modify it to your needs, i used a [iife](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/IIFE) as fetch method returns a promise

you can do:

```js
<message>.channel.send(`the result is ${response}`)
```

as a example adapted from the above given code

ps: rather than using a api for math you could use [mathjs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mathjs) package (which your using, just its the api version)

Edited: forgot of encodeURIComponent in fetch request url, or you will get a `Only absolute URLs are supported` error

Answer (score 0):

You don't need JSON just to get the value of the query parameter from the URL. If you just need to get the number you can try it with URLSearchParams:

```
console.log(window.location.search); //output: '?expr=2*2'

var params = new URLSearchParams('?expr=2*2');

console.log(params.has('expr')); //output: 'true';
console.log(params.get('expr')); //output: '2*2';
```

you get the value from params.get('expr'));

Comment: hmm, he dont have access to 'window' in node.js (as he tagged it discord.js, which means they must be using node.js)

Comment: @TYPICALNINJA Change window.location.search to the paramsString then.

var params = new URLSearchParams('?expr=2*2');